# Create a user on the docker host from inside a container

Tags: linux, docker

I am trying to create a user "foo" on the docker host from within a container, but it fails.
The following files are volume-mounted **read-write** in the container:

- /etc/group:/etc/group:rw
- /etc/gshadow:/etc/gshadow:rw
- /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:rw
- /etc/shadow:/etc/shadow:rw

When running the following command as root inside the container:

```
adduser --debug --system --shell /bin/bash --group foo
```

Then the output is:

```
Selecting UID from range 100 to 999 ...
Selecting GID from range 100 to 999 ...
Adding system user `foo' (UID 130) ...
Adding new group `foo' (GID 139) ...
/sbin/groupadd -g 139 foo
groupadd: failure while writing changes to /etc/group
adduser: `/sbin/groupadd -g 139 foo' returned error code 10. Exiting.
```

Permissions of these files look okay to me. Both on the docker host as well as inside the container, permissions are the same.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1167 apr 14 12:51 /etc/group
-rw-r----- 1 root shadow  969 apr 14 12:51 /etc/gshadow
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3072 apr 14 12:51 /etc/passwd
-rw-r----- 1 root shadow 1609 apr 14 12:51 /etc/shadow
```

I have also tried chattr -i on these files, but it still fails.

Is there some other file that I have overlooked and needs to be mounted? Is it even possible what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Generally you run things in containers so that they can't modify files like the host's encrypted password file; even if the container is compromised the host is at least somewhat protected.  If you need to create a system user, create it directly on the host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you mount an individual file, you end up mounting the inode of that file with the bind mount. And when you write to the file, many tools create a new file, with a new inode, and replace the existing file with that. This avoids partial reads, and other file corruption risks if you were to modify the file in place.

What you are attempting to do is likely a very bad idea, it's the very definition of a container escape, allowing the container to setup credentials on the host. If you really need host access, I'd mount the folder in a different location because containers have other files that are automatically mounted in /etc. So you could say `/etc:/host/etc` and access the files in the container under `/host/etc`. Just realize that's even a larger security hole.

Note, if the entire goal is to avoid permission issues between the host and the container, there are much better ways to do this, but that would be an X-Y problem.

Comment: I'm aware of the security implications of this, but this would only be done in a controlled environment, so not really an issue. Mounting the complete /etc gets me a little further, but then run into other issues like the shell binary is not found. Sharing the HOME with other containers is also troublesome. I'm going to move the user setup to the docker host and just mount /etc/passwd readonly. Anyways... I'm going to accept your answer because you were right on the money as to why it failed what I was trying.

Comment: just, no. Please.